# Core Data entity with properties that point to objects

Tags: core-data, entity-relationship, mkannotation

I'm not sure how to maintain a bi-directional relationship between my core data entities and some objects that are instantiated when the entities are created and committed to the database.

I have many subclassed MKAnnotation objects with one-to-one relationships to the entities. Every time my fetchedResultsController executes a new fetch, I am assuming that the results from a previous fetch are released and the NSManagedObjects that are fetched are remapped in memory. So my one-to-one relationships are broken. If I can save a pointer to the MKAnnotation objects in core data, that would fix half of the problem (the relationship in one direction). Does this make sense? How would you do this?

I delete all of the core data content when the application is restarted, so long term persistence of the relationship information is not a concern that I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mixing pointers and managed objects is usually futile because Core Data has so many optimizations in place that direct memory management is all but impossible e.g. an object may revert to a fault.

You're really going about this the wrong way.  Core Data isn't primarily a persistence API, its a data modeling API intended to provide the complete model layer of a Mode-View-Controller design app. As such, you can use it without saving anything at all. If you are using Core Data and you have data such as map annotation, the annotation should be modeled in Core Data. Doing so will simplify everything.

Since there is no MSAnnotation class but merely a MKAnnotation protocol, the simplest solution in this case would be to create a NSManagedObject class that implements the MKAnnotation protocol. You can either convert location data like `CLLocationCoordinate2D` into NSValues or better yet, just make attributes for them. Since the class implements the protocol, you could pass the managed objects anywhere you would pass any protocol object.

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying. I am going to implement the MKAnnotation properties as transient properties in the managed object entity. I see that the actaul map annotation views are updated as needed, and already have the bindings I was looking for. I have some questions about implementing trsnsient properties, but I have posted them in another question.

Comment: If you don't actually need to model or persist the MKAnnotation properties, you can just add them as unmodeled properties of the custom NSManagedObject subclass. Unmodeled properties are those found in the class but not the entity. The managed object context ignores them.